Azure Devops Pipeline conditional expression
How can I use loops in condition expression for a task?
I have a stage in pipeline that depends on other stages in the same pipeline. Stage names are dynamically generated. How can I add a condition that checks if any one of the stage has executed successfully?
For e.g.,
parameters:
- name: modules
  default:
    - name: module1
      type: typeA
    - name: module2
      type: typeB

stages:
- ${{ each module in parameters.modules}}:
  - stage: ${{module.name}}
    jobs:
    - job: build${{module.name}}

- stage: result
  dependsOn:
  - ${{ each module in parameters.modules}}:
    - ${{module.name}}
  condition: and(not(failed()), or any of the dependent jobs succeeded)
  jobs:
  - job: deployStage

I tried accessing the status of the stage/task in powershell inline script, but that also does not return any results: "dependencies.$stagename.$jobname.outputs"

Consider adding a condition property to the parameter elements and use filtered arrays to dynamically set the dependencies and conditions of the final stage.
Working example:
trigger: none

parameters:
  - name: modules
    type: object
    default:
      - name: module1
        type: typeA
        condition: "eq(dependencies.module1.result, 'Succeeded')"
        # condition: in(dependencies.module1.result, 'Succeeded', 'SucceededWithIssues')
        exitCode: 0 # For testing purposes only: 0 for success, other for failure
      - name: module2
        type: typeB
        condition: "eq(dependencies.module2.result, 'Succeeded')"
        # condition: in(dependencies.module2.result, 'Succeeded', 'SucceededWithIssues')
        exitCode: 0 # For testing purposes only: 0 for success, other for failure

stages:
  - ${{ each module in parameters.modules }}:
    - stage: ${{ module.name }}
      displayName: ${{ module.name }}
      dependsOn: []
      jobs:
        - job: build${{ module.name }}
          displayName: ${{ module.name }}
          steps:
            - checkout: none
            - script: |
                exit ${{ module.exitCode }}
              displayName: 'Run ${{ module.name }} - ${{ module.type }}'

  - stage: result
    displayName: 'Result'
    dependsOn: ${{ parameters.modules.*.name }}
    condition: or(${{ join(',', parameters.modules.*.condition) }})
    jobs:
      - job: deploy
        displayName: 'Deploy'
        steps:
          - checkout: none
          - script: |
              echo "Conditon: or(${{ join(',', parameters.modules.*.condition) }})"
            displayName: 'Print condition'

Expression or(${{ join(',', parameters.modules.*.condition) }}) will generate the following string:

or(eq(dependencies.module1.result, 'Succeeded'),eq(dependencies.module2.result, 'Succeeded'))


Works like a charm. Thanks!
